# Ignite hanging with TCP Discover Statistics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, bigdata, ignite

I run two jars. each one starts an ignite instance(ports 47500 and 47501). the jar fetch rows from kafka , process , put to cache, persist ....etc.

the two jars start, fetch rows from kafka in the first poll, perform processing and then hang and keep giving me these logs ....

```
10/05/2018 16:39:48  INFO [tcp-disco-stats-printer-#4%cluster-VEON%] 
TcpDiscoverySpi: Discovery SPI statistics [statistics=TcpDiscoveryStatistics 
[joinStartedTs=1525962688220, joinFinishedTs=1525962706508, 
crdSinceTs=1525962706498, joinedNodesCnt=1, failedNodesCnt=0, leftNodesCnt=0, 
ackTimeoutsCnt=0, sockTimeoutsCnt=0, rcvdMsgs= 
{TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=474, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=1, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=1, TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=2, 
TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=35, TcpDiscoveryConnectionCheckMessage=706, 
TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=39}, procMsgs= 
{TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=715, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=1, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=1, TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=2, 
TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=53, TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=76}, 
avgMsgsSndTimes={TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=0, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=10, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=0, 
TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=10, TcpDiscoveryConnectionCheckMessage=0, 
TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=0, TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=0}, 
maxMsgsSndTimes={TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=10, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=10, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=0, 
TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=10, TcpDiscoveryConnectionCheckMessage=42, 
TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=0, TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=0}, sentMsgs= 
{TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=474, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=1, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=1, TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=1, 
TcpDiscoveryConnectionCheckMessage=706, TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=35, 
TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=33}, avgMsgsAckTimes= 
{TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=0, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=10, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=0, TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=10, 
TcpDiscoveryConnectionCheckMessage=0, TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=0, 
TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=0}, maxMsgsAckTimes= 
{TcpDiscoveryMetricsUpdateMessage=10, TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage=10, 
TcpDiscoveryNodeAddFinishedMessage=0, TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage=10, 
TcpDiscoveryConnectionCheckMessage=42, TcpDiscoveryDiscardMessage=0, 
TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage=0}, avgMsgQueueTime=0, maxMsgQueueTime=11, 
ringMsgsSent=35, avgRingMsgTime=0, maxRingMsgTime=121, 
maxRingTimeMsgCls=TcpDiscoveryNodeAddedMessage, avgMsgProcTime=0, 
maxMsgProcTime=91, maxProcTimeMsgCls=TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage, 
sockReadersCreated=3, sockReadersRmv=2, avgSrvSockInitTime=3, 
maxSrvSockInitTime=10, clientSockCreatedCnt=2, avgClientSockInitTime=15, 
maxClientSockInitTime=21, pendingMsgsRegistered=35, pendingMsgsDiscarded=0], 
spiState=CONNECTED, coord=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8a03f4a3-a631-42e7-bdf2- 
b062e1e977b6, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.19.1.14, 127.0.0.1, 172.16.44.139, 
172.23.48.1], sockAddrs=[WEGMM250132-O5F.TD.TERADATA.COM/10.19.1.14:47501, 
/172.16.44.139:47501, /172.23.48.1:47501, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47501, 
/127.0.0.1:47501], discPort=47501, order=1, intOrder=1, 
lastExchangeTime=1525962688210, loc=true, ver=2.0.0#20170430-sha1:d4eef3c6, 
isClient=false], next=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ee98d2ff-40fe-4981-8a59- 
1b12b478bc11, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.19.1.14, 127.0.0.1, 172.16.44.139, 
172.23.48.1], sockAddrs=[WEGMM250132-O5F.TD.TERADATA.COM/10.19.1.14:47500, 
/172.23.48.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, 
/172.16.44.139:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, 
lastExchangeTime=1525962714266, loc=false, ver=2.0.0#20170430-sha1:d4eef3c6, 
isClient=false], intOrder=1, topSize=2, leavingNodesSize=0, 
failedNodesSize=0, 
joiningNodesSize=0, pendingCustomMsgs=0, msgWorker.queue.size=0, clients=0, 
clientWorkers=0, lastUpdate=05/10/2018 16:39:47, heapFree=5727M, 
heapTotal=5888M]
```

When I stop one of the jars, the other jar continue working normally and fetch all the remaining data. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you add more context? This looks a bit like exchange hanging, since it would print a lot of messages. Can you attach the whole log, with IGNITE_QUIET=false?

Comment: @alamar here are the logs

for the 1st jar .... port 47500
http://www.mediafire.com/file/igih95shmtz2710/tr_framework_full1.log

for the 2nd jar .... port 47501
http://www.mediafire.com/file/vsyseseuezif5ky/tr_framework_full2.log

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @alamar do you have any input on this problem?

Comment: From the logs it is not apparent than anything is wrong. Are you sure that it's not your code that stops progressing?

Comment: @alamar it works normally when on one single node ?! what are the areas should I revise in your opinion?

Comment: Try running this in a different environment (e.g. on a local machine if you're using multiple servers now). Try looking at the task dependencies - perhaps there is some kind of a deadlock among the jobs running on your nodes. Right now this question is way to broad to be answered.